# Pyspark Error ReduceByKey

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark, key-value, reduce

I have a problem with my `reduceByKey()`. I don't display the result... I have keys, values... But impossible to use `reduceByKey`...

```py
data_test_bis = data_textfile.map(lambda x: (x.split(",")[8].encode("utf-8").replace('"','').replace("'",''), 1)).filter(lambda x: x[0].startswith('Ru'))#.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
#data_test_filter = data_test_bis.filter(lambda x: x[0].startswith('"R'))
print("TEST FILTER !")
print(type(data_test_bis))
print(data_test_bis.take(5))
print(data_test_bis.keys().take(10))
print(data_test_bis.values().take(10))
```

Results:

```
TEST FILTER !
<class 'pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD'> 
[('Rueil-Malmaison', 1), ('Ruse', 1), ('Rueil Malmaison', 1), ('Rueil-Malmaison', 1), ('Ruda Slaska', 1)]
['Rueil-Malmaison', 'Ruse', 'Rueil Malmaison', 'Rueil-Malmaison', 'Ruda Slaska', 'Ruisbroek (Belgique)', 'Ruda \xc3\x85\xc5\xa1l\xc3\x84\xe2\x80\xa6ska', 'Rueil malmaison', 'Rueil', 'Ruisbroek']
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

When i try this one, there are an error:

```py
print(data_test_bis.reduceByKey(add).take(10))
```

or

```py
print(data_test_bis.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y).take(10))
```

Error:

```
17/01/03 17:47:09 ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 18 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/spark/julien/Test_.py", line 89, in <module>
    test()
  File "/home/spark/julien/Test_.py", line 33, in test
    print(data_test_bis.reduceByKey(lambda x, y:x+y).take(10))
  File "/home/spark/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1297, in take
  File "/home/spark/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 939, in runJob
  File "/home/spark/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/home/spark/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
  File "/home/spark/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 18 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 18.3 in stage 3.0 (TID 67, 10.0.15.7): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/home/spark/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2346, in pipeline_func
  File "/home/spark/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2346, in pipeline_func
  File "/home/spark/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 317, in func
  File "/home/spark/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1776, in combineLocally
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 236, in mergeValues
    for k, v in iterator:
  File "/home/spark/julien/Test_.py", line 25, in <lambda>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't understand why i have an IndexError...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just repeat after me: *I will never assume that an unstructured data source is well formed*.

Things like:

```
... .map(lambda x: (x.split(",")[8].encode("utf-8") ...)
```

are great for quick tutorials but are useless in practice. In general never depend on the assumptions that:

- Data has specific shape (there will be for example 9, comma-separated fields).
- Encoding / decoding will succeed (here we actually can but it is not true in general).

At least include a minimalistic exception handling:

```
def parse_to_pair(line):
    try:
        key = (line
            .split(",")[8]
            .encode("utf-8")
            .replace('"', '')
            .replace("'", ''))

        return [(key, 1)]
    except:
        return []
```

and use `flatMap`:

```
data_textfile.flatMap(parse_to_pair)
```

**Notes**:

- You can skip `encode` by calling `SparkContext.textFile` with `use_unicode` set to `False`. It will:

  - Use `str` instead of `unicode` in Python 2.
  - Use `bytes` in Python 3.
- You should not only make sure that line contains at least 9 fields, but that it contains an expected number of fields.
- If you by any chance have `csv` as an input use `csv` reader.